# Filling table from mysql data using php pdo prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been trying to switch mysql statements over to PDO and Prepared Statements, but just not getting it. I have a form that users input data and this posts to a mysql database. This I believe I've figured out because it actually works. Here is the code.

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO info(lakeid, name, size, depth, access, sports, beach, atlantic, 
                bluegill, brook, brown, catfish, coho, crappie, king, lake, largemouth, muskie,
                pike, perch, pumkinseed, rainbow, rock, smallmouth, steelhead, sturgeon, walleye, 
                comments) 
            VALUES (:lakeid, :name, :size, :depth, :access, :sports, :beach, :atlantic, :bluegill, 
                :brook, :brown, :catfish, :coho, :crappie,:king, :lake, :largemouth, :muskie, :pike, 
                :perch, :pumkinseed, :rainbow, :rock, :smallmouth, :steelhead, :sturgeon, :walleye, 
                :comments )");

            $stmt->bindParam(':lakeid', $lakeid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':size', $size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':depth', $depth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':access', $access, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sports', $sports, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':beach', $beach, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':atlantic', $atlantic, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':bluegill', $bluegill, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':brook', $brook, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':brown', $brown, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':catfish', $catfish, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':coho', $coho, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':crappie', $crappie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':king', $king, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lake', $lake, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':largemouth', $largemouth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':muskie', $muskie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pike', $pike, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':perch', $perch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pumkinseed', $pumkinseed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':rainbow', $rainbow, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':rock', $rock, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':smallmouth', $smallmouth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':steelhead', $steelhead, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sturgeon', $sturgeon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':walleye', $walleye, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':comments', $comments, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
```

My problem has been getting this info to print back out on the original page into a table. I've tried several tutorials but none of them seem to be helping. Any suggestions on this would be helpful. 
Thanks a bunch.

Here is the edited code used to print the user input into a table. Again I don't know much about PDO, but trying to protect against injection. This actually prints all the correct input into the table. Is there anything else I should worry about?
Thanks for any replies.

```
        $stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM info WHERE lakeid = ?");
        $stm->execute(array("$counties"));
        $data = $stm->fetchAll();



Print "<table border cellpadding=5>"; 
    Print "<tr><th>Name:</th> <th>Size:</th> <th>Depth:</th> <th>Boat Access:</th> <th>All Sports:</th> <th>Public Beach:</th> <th>Fish Species:</th> <th>Comments:</th></tr>"; 
    foreach($data as $inform  ) 

    {
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print " <td>" .$inform['name']."</td> "; 
    Print "<td>".$inform['size'] . " </td>";
    Print " <td>".$inform['depth'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$inform['access'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$inform['sports'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$inform['beach'] . " </td>";
    Print" <td>".$inform['atlantic'] ."\n". $inform['bluegill']. "\n". $inform['brook']. "\n". $inform['brown']. 
    "\n". $inform['catfish']. "\n". $inform['coho']. "\n". $inform['crappie']. "\n". $inform['king']. "\n". $inform['lake']. 
    "\n". $inform['largemouth']. "\n". $inform['muskie']. "\n". $inform['pike']. "\n". $inform['perch']. "\n". $inform['pumkinseed'].  
    "\n". $inform['rainbow']. "\n". $inform['rock']. "\n". $inform['smallmouth']. "\n". $inform['steelhead'].  "\n". $inform['sturgeon'].
    "\n". $inform['walleye'].   "</td>";
    Print " <td>".$inform['comments'] . "</td> "; "</tr>"; 
    } 

    Print "</table>";
```

Comment: Could you add the code you've tried to your question, please?

Comment: I believe if I understand you will have to run a select query ob your page where you want to display the result where in where clause you will put the id as lastInsertId() - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what tutorial you tried, but your retrieval attempt is against all SQL rules.

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM info");
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
<? foreach ($row as $value): ?>
    <td><?=$value?></td>
<? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

is just an example. You need a tutorial on basic SQL first, I believe.

Comment: I know I am completely new to this and that gives me something to look into. When you are new it's hard to find what to look at first. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I edited the code and it now actually works. Does anybody know if that is all I need to do for security (like sql injection).